# Is it possible to receive and send data to mysql from and to android firebase using visual studios

Tags: c#, android, mysql, firebase

I want to create an android app for a project using visual studios(C#). The app is based on a computer system that uses mySQL for the database. Is it possible to collect data from the database and send it to the app and vice versa, if so please help. If not, what should I do.

The program saves sport fixtures and results to a mySQL database. I know it is not possible to link mySQL DB with Firebase, but there should be a way to collect the the info needed.

Comment: Since both Firebase and mySQL have APIs, you should be able to write code to connect the two of them together. But that's an entire project, and it's hard to help with something so broad here. Did you already create the app? What step are you stuck at?

Comment: I am still designing the UI, I just wondered about that before I start with the coding of the app.

Comment: @Hennie I would suggest you this library, if you want to directly connect to mysql. I tested alot of libraries but this library is the best one. : https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can (I assume you are using xamarin to develop android app) by downloading dll or driver to connect to mysql server but this practice is very discouraged. Ask anyone and they will told you to use webservice to bridge your app and database. But if you really really want to connect directly to your mysql database, you can use [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.MySql.Data/).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.